# Select a hidden element with PHPunit

Tags: selenium, phpunit, hidden

Is it possible to locate an element altho it is hidden? I want a function that looks for my tooltip that says something was not filled correctly in my form.

the function looks like this:

```
public function checkTooltip()
{
    $element = $this->byClassName('tooltip');

    if ($element->displayed())
    {
        echo "something was not filled correctly";
    }
}


$var1->value('hello');
$this->checkTooltip();
$var2->value('world');
$this->checkTooltip();
$var3->value('!');
$this->checkTooltip();
```

This works perfectly when the tooltip appears but if there is nothing wrong I get the message:

```
"PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException: no such element"
```

And this make sence because it's hidden when nothing is going wrong but I want to select that element anyways, becouse I want my test to make sure that it's not vissible during my test to make sure everything is okey.So is there a way to select a hidden element using phpunit_Selenium2TestCase?

Comment: You should be able to select an element that is not visible (as long as it is in the HTML).  You will not, however, be able to perform actions on it.

Comment: Just found out from the developers that the element is actually created and then removed from the html when it pops up. How can I handle this? Since the element is'nt there unless something is wrong how can I check for it?

Comment: `if (driver.findElements(.....).size()==0)` That is how I would do it in Java.  Sorry, I don't know PHP.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but that wont work in php, if I try to find an element that dont exist the test will get an error and stop.

Comment: Not if you do findElements() (Note the S).  It will return an empty list, rather than throw an error.

Comment: if that is the case that would be great but when I try to use it I get **Fatal error: Call to undefined function byClassName()**  or **BadMethodCallException: The command 'findElements' is not existent or not suppor
ted yet.** the code looks like this http://pastebin.com/BPABjfav the errors are thrown in the order I pasted here.

Comment: Okey so the fault was that php is just elements not findElements so worked perfect :D thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked as a charm!

```
public function checkError()
{       
    $tooltip  = $this->elements($this->using('css selector')->value('div.active div.invalid'));

    if(count($tooltip) != 0)
    {   
        foreach ($tooltip as $tool)
        {   
            $warning = $tool->text();   
            echo "You got a invalid tooltip with this message '".$warning."'";           
        }
    }    
}
```